# How to store different classes in a variable?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

```
class Resources{

protected:
    int size;
    char repchar;   //Representing Char
public:
    Resources(int size=0,char repchar=' ');
    char getchar();
    int getsize();
        //copy const
        //destructor };


class Bone:public Resources{
private:
    int BoneScore;
public:
    Bone(int size,char repchar,int BoneScore);
};


class Trap:public Resources{
/*  private:
          bool active=false;*/
    public:
        Trap();
     //   bool activehigh();
        };
class Food:public Resources{
    private:
        int energy;
    public:
        Food(int size,char repchar,int energy);
};


class Water:public Resources{
    private:
        int energy;
    public:
        Water();
};
```

Hello everyone, Basically I am a beginner in C++.I am trying to create a map-based game.I will put resources to the map randomly ,then they will collect turn by turn.At the end , the program will calculate points come from bones ,and decide regarding winner.Therefore,I want to store Resources taken by players .What i imply is the fact that i would like to store different classes in a variable.Thank you for helping in advance.I have 4 different resources bones,traps,water,foods.

Comment: Take a look at [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: I am checking .Thank you

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly, then if you declare a variable of type Resources* then you should be able to assign it to any class that derived from it.  Something like Resources* res = water; rest = food; etc...

Comment: Yes, now i realized that.I can use Resources * for all.I did not know this feature :)

Answer (score 0):

This is called polymorphism:

```
class base {};
class child1 : public base{};
class child2 : public base{};


base* b1 = new child1();
base* b2 = new child2();
```

Consider my `base` class as your `Resource` class.  You can do something like this:

```
typedef std::list<Resource*> Resources;


Resources resources;

// Map setup
resources.push_back(new Bone());
resources.push_back(new Trap());
resources.push_back(new Water());

// Interact with each one:
for(auto& resource : resources)
    resource->getsize(); // Call a method from Resource::

// Interact with traps:
for(auto& resource : resources)
    if (resource->getchar() == 't') // If the resource is a trap
        dynamic_cast<Trap*>(resource)->trigger(); // Trap-specific method  

// clean-up
for(auto it = resources.begin(); it != resources.end(); )
{
    delete *it;
    it = resources.erase(it);
}
```